# Get a better seat post that will last longer

Tags: mountain-bike, saddle

I took off the seat post for my Huffy MTB.

The pic shows the measurements of the old post. (Ed: The actual measurement is 28.6mm, see comment)

Can someone help me find one that will outlast the factory seat post?

[image]

Here is the seat I just bought.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's an extremely odd looking seat post.  That said, what's the problem with it?  How/why didnt it last?

Comment: @AndyP wild guess: it's actually the clamp not shown in the picture that's broken (https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86870/repair-damage-to-my-seatpost-clamp)

Comment: Does the diameter stamped on the post above the open jaws of the micrometer say "28.5" or "28.6"? Your replacement seatpost will need to have the same exact rating.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the saddle you want to use with the seatpost?

Comment: @Armand is asking this because 28.6mm is one of the standard seatpost diameters. 28.5mm is not. It could be an issue of manufacturing tolerances, however (i.e. they were aiming for a nominal diameter of 28.6mm, but their process has poor tolerances and you got an undersized post).

Comment: It measures 28.6 mm. @Weiwen Ng

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to answer the question without knowing what the problem with the original seat post was, other than that someone drilled a hole through it. However, any 28.6mm seatpost with built in clamp should do better.

The setup with separate seat post and clamp stamped from sheet metal is usually reserved for the extreme budget bikes, because the normal single bolt posts don't cost much more but work much better.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for "28.6mm seatpost" and there's a plethora of options.

The 28.6mm diameter is the most important and must match.  The length needs to be no-shorter than your current seatpost.

Your choice of materials in a new product will be mostly Aluminium, which is ideal.   A Carbon Fibre one will be expensive and unnecessary.

You'll be able to choose a Black finish or a Chrome/shiny finish - functionally they're the same.

The saddle clamp will come built-into the new seat post, and you'll need a 5mm or 6mm or maybe 8mm hex driver to adjust the bolts.

Something like this with one bolt, or there are some variants with two bolts.

[image]

Comment: What about this one? https://www.amazon.com/PLATTBK-350mm-Aluminum-Seatpost-31-6mm/dp/B09NM686KX/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=28.6%2Bseatpost&qid=1671583184&sr=8-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUE4TVQyWElaT05LWUwmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA2OTg1NjVZUUIwT05LTjNPVk4mZW5jcnlwdGVkQWRJZD1BMDk3NTM2MDJLSkVKVEdKOUozUkwmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl&th=1&psc=1 @Criggie

Comment: @fixit7 looks like the same kind of thing to me.

Comment: Alright. So will it work? @Criggie

Comment: @fixit7 as long as you pick the same 28.6mm measurement as your existing seatpost, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's a seat post for vintage saddles. Not the modern ones with rails. You cannot find a decent seatpost without clamps. You will need to buy a new saddle with 28.6mm seatpost, or get a cheap Chinese one to use it with your old saddle..you won't find a FSA or pro seatpost with old type clamps.

Comment: It was actually used with a saddle with rails https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86870/repair-damage-to-my-seatpost-clamp (linked in the comments above and you actually answered that question yourself).

Comment: @Barış Atasoy When you say "get a cheap Chinese one", are you implying something?

Comment: No reputable manufacturer makes them anymore, because these are very old